# Edmodo Image Cropper support for different languages

Tags: android, crop

I am using Edmodo's Image Cropper in my apps. I am searching and cannot find if there is any support for different languages.

The activity shows a button on the top right corner with "CROP" label. I need to change it into the many languages supported by the apps.

Is there any place where this label could be changed?

[Edmodo crop activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sDIn.gif)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `CropImageView` and not Sample project which shows usage of library. There is no "CROP" label provided by library itself. Put `CropImageView` inside any activity you want and use any labels you want.

Comment: I am not using the sample. I am using `CropImageView` as in the example of github.

Comment: `CropImageView` is basically `ImageView` which you should put in your layout and it has nothing to do with "Crop" button in toolbar/actionbar of activity where you use it.

Comment: And? Is that the answer of my question? I repeat "Is there any place where this label could be changed?"

Comment: Edmodo crop library doesn't use any labels or text. If your question how to localize android app, please take a look on official android dev site - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Comment: You are not understanding my question.

Comment: @JavierSivianes It seems nobody does

Comment: I don't think this answers the question

Comment: @MichaelFourre it is answer. He uses sample project of library, instead of using library itself. Library provides `CropImageView` which should be used, and there is no any "Crop" labels provided by library.